# Python log handler forward different messages to different files

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can we send logs to files based on the log format ? Ex: if the message contains “abc”, send it to abc.txt, “secure” to secure.txt

Comment: How do you know what containing word will be in the title of txt?

Comment: Example input/output? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I get the events from azure event hub and they are parsed before being forwarded to another server or written to a file.

Comment: @PratikGandhi - I use FileHandler. But now that I need to write to two files, I will need two file handlers but what is written to the files depends on the LOG LEVEL. The problem here is I want to keep the LOG LEVEL as INFO for everything.

Comment: @Ravi thanks for the clarification. Can you edit the question with some more info, what is your code look like, and what is the exact problem? In what format you are getting input and what does the output look like?